# Querying a Postgres with Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I am slightly confused by the output i'm receiving from my Postgres when querying it with the use of go.
Since I am very new to this I have a hard time even forming the right question for this problem I have, so I'll just leave a code block here, with the output I'm receiving and what I expected to happen. I hope this makes it more understandable.

The connection to the postgres db seems to work fine

```
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title FROM blogs;")                                                                                                                                                      
        fmt.Println("output", rows)
```

However, this is the output I am receiving.

```
output &{0xc4200ea180 0x4c0e20 0xc42009a3c0 0x4b4f90 <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}
```

As I said, I am new to postgres and go, and I have no Idea what I am dealing with here.

I was expecting my entire table to return in a somewhat readable format.

Comment: `rows` is a struct, and you're printing out the internal values. Follow the documentation on how to use the [`*sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) returned from a `DB.Query`: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query

Answer (score 4):

> I was expecting my entire table to return in a somewhat readable format.

It does not come back in a "readable" format, why would it?

`Query` returns a struct that you can use to iterate through the rows that matched the query.

Adapting the example in the docs to your case, and assuming your `title` field is a `VARCHAR`, something like this should work for you:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title FROM blogs;")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    var title string
    if err := rows.Scan(&title); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(title)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```